# Youtube-dl trouble outputting in mp3

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I wrote this function.  I am trying to have it output the mp3 file but it isn't working.  I keep getting this error.  I have tried messing with putting .mp3 on "output_filepath" or "%(ext)s" with no avail.

```
def start_extraction(url, output_file):

    output_filepath = 'music/%s.mp3' % output_file
    temp_filepath = 'temp/%s-%s.%s' % (uuid.uuid4(), output_file, '%(ext)s')


    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', # choice of quality
    'extractaudio' : True,      # only keep the audio
    'audioformat' : 'mp3',      # convert to mp3
    'outtmpl': temp_filepath,  # name the location
    'noplaylist' : True,        # only download single song, not playlist
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
     }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
      result = ydl.download([url])
    #
    if result == 0:
        # Move the temporary file to the proper location.
        shutil.move(temp_filepath, output_filepath)
return result
```

So I get this error

```
[youtube] TZB8HRrJ0KM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] TZB8HRrJ0KM: Extracting video information
[youtube] TZB8HRrJ0KM: Downloading DASH manifest
Done downloading, now converting ...
05:54:31 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'temp/61499bc8-0c2e-4719-8556-826af80fd028-How_To_Shave_Your_Beard_Like_A_Man.%(ext)s'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/yout/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 557, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/vagrant/yout/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 492, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/yout/worker.py", line 100, in extract_audio
    extraction_result = start_extraction(url, audio_filename)
  File "/vagrant/yout/worker.py", line 130, in start_extraction
    shutil.move(temp_filepath, output_filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'temp/61499bc8-0c2e-4719-8556-826af80fd028-How_To_Shave_Your_Beard_Like_A_Man.%(ext)s'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/yout/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 557, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/vagrant/yout/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 492, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/yout/worker.py", line 100, in extract_audio
    extraction_result = start_extraction(url, audio_filename)
  File "/vagrant/yout/worker.py", line 130, in start_extraction
    shutil.move(temp_filepath, output_filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'temp/61499bc8-0c2e-4719-8556-826af80fd028-How_To_Shave_Your_Beard_Like_A_Man.%(ext)s'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after a while of debuging.  I found out that the file was getting saved as a m4a.  Also needed to replace the variable since it mutated.  So for anyone who is having using youtube-dl with itunes here is the solution I was able to come up with.

```
def start_extraction(url, output_file):

    output_filepath = 'music/%s.mp3' % output_file
    temp_filepath = 'temp/%s-%s.%s' % (uuid.uuid4(), output_file, '%(ext)s')


    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', # choice of quality
    'extractaudio' : True,      # only keep the audio
    'audioformat' : 'mp3',      # convert to mp3
    'outtmpl': temp_filepath,  # name the location
    'noplaylist' : True,        # only download single song, not playlist
    'postprocessors': [{
      'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
      'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
      'preferredquality': '192',
      }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
     }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
      result = ydl.download([url])
    #
    if result == 0:
        # Move the temporary file to the proper location.
        temp_filepath = temp_filepath.replace('.%(ext)s', ".mp3")
        shutil.move(temp_filepath, output_filepath)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the wrong variable name, `output_file` should be replaced by `output_filepath`.

`temp_filepath = 'temp/%s-%s.%s' % (uuid.uuid4(), output_file, '%(ext)s')`

This line is causing the issue. String is not formatted properly.

`temp_filepath = 'temp/%s-%s' % (uuid.uuid4(), output_filepath)`

or

`temp_filepath = 'temp/%s-%(title)s.%(ext)s' % uuid.uuid4()`

or

`temp_filepath = 'temp/%s-%s.%(ext)s' % (uuid.uuid4(), output_filepath)`

Comment: I haven't used this library myself, but if you look at [the documentation for it](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template), it certainly seems to support templates like `%(ext)s` in the filename.

Comment: When I take out the %(ext)s it works but the file wont play in itunes but thats another problem I suppose

Comment: why did you rejected answer?

Comment: actually your updated answer none of the options work :-/ they give a mapping error.

Comment: Yeah, its bizzar, the answer you have that works does not actually use the %(ext)s with out a mapping error.  And then that causes the bug in [this issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/1470) so I'm going to have to say its not correct.  Sorry and thanks for the help so far.